# How harmful are kicks to the private parts in krav maga?

Tags: safety, krav-maga

I did KM for a year. Kicks to the crotch are certainly normal here. I never had any problems, because those guys were careful even if everybody had a jock strap on.

Now I moved to another place and found another KM club there. Here they are somehow more harsh. They do not hesitate to kick your private parts a little harder. This hurts even with a jock strap on. The pain is not unbearable but still every kick hurts. They even somehow find it to be amusing and are making jokes about that.

I would not consider myself a wimp, I already did some other things (kickboxing, taekwondo..). But still I wonder, does this somehow affect your potency? I mean those guys seem to be professionals and do not seem to care. So they either must be pretty confident that this does not have any longterm side effects on their sexual life or they simply do not bother.

Any experience? Btw, by habit I somehow tend to block kicks like this with my knee so they get hurt on their feet every time. They must be hating me for that.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First and foremost: **do not take medical advice from strangers on the Internet!** Go and seek professional medical help.

Secondly, from your (very limited) exposition, this clubs seems to encourage bullying and has a clear disregard for basic safety. I would strongly suggest you do not train with them.

Finally, you can condition your body to disregard pain. Generally, this involves repeated trauma till your body grow defences to prevent further damage. Note that there is trauma/damage in the first place. So, you *could* train yourself to take kicks to the privates but you probably will damage them in the process.  However, I am unaware of any medical research on the subject.  A quick Google search lead me to [ACSM's Primary Care Sports Medicine
 edited by Douglas McKeag, James L. Moeller](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=KoeRrA_-td0C&pg=PA235&lpg=PA235&dq=trauma+to+genitals+in+martial+arts&source=bl&ots=3g4lmjt54C&sig=ZiT8fWR01W-he7BlOhbA0sIfjfU&hl=en&sa=X&ei=ZFOhU-fXMI6b0wWtj4CgAg&ved=0CEUQ6AEwBA#v=onepage&q=trauma%20to%20genitals%20in%20martial%20arts&f=false) which to my layman eyes seems to be good start and contains a long list of references for you to check.

Comment: That's kind of a stupid way to train, even with a cup on.  Cups are for ACCIDENTAL groin injuries.  Sounds like these guys are way too nonchalant.  May I suggest a traditional martial art?  If you can find a school where the instructor knows what fighting is really like, you may also find that they take the instruction more seriously, in addition to being more precise with their techniques.

Comment: @TheWudangKid I have been looking for more traditional stuff but KM seemed like a perfect combination of strength + endurance and technics training without the constant pressure to be committed to go on tournaments. Any Ideas? tried Wing Tsun and Kickboxing?

Comment: Wing Chun can be really good if you find a school that does two things A) teaches Wing Chun that is both authentic and realistic and B) doesn't spend more time bad-mouthing other arts and even other Wing Chun branches than it does training.  You can't go wrong with some good ol' kickboxing, but you may find you outgrow the limited range of techniques it provides.  If you can find a JKD school, they will probably also do WC as well as Kali, two very good arts, and they won't be as political about their WC.

Comment: "your body grow defences to prevent further damage" actually means either nerve damage or scar tissue.  In this case, because the groin is so sensitive, that would be nerve damage.  Regularly taking shots is probably not a good plan, regardless of how macho folks get to feel at the end of the day...

Comment: I would also advise to develop your own defences against groin attacks like proper posture that does not open your groin so readily to the attack. However, it seems to me, that this is the type of thing your classmates might point out to you.

Comment: **If you have something to add, either edit the post or post your own answer.** Remember, comments are going to be deleted. That came out harsher than I wanted...

Comment: Yup, the conversation would be a great thing to take to [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2353/the-dojo) except where it is leading to edits.

Comment: I'll do you guys a favor and make a jock strap with a big matted pad for "accidental" protection.

Answer (score 1):

Irrespective of creed or style, kicks to the crotch are dangerous. See a professional doctor.